# How to make sure code is run every time viewController is viewed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How can I have my app run my code every time the app is viewed and not just every time it is opened? Right now I have to exit it, and open it again to run the code.

My app pulls data via JSON and displays it in labels. All of my code is in viewDidLoad.

Is the answer in putting all of the code in viewDidAppear?

Thanks in advance

Here is the whole code:

```
    //
//  ViewController.swift
//  KitesurfioApp
//
//  Created by Lasse Kristensen on 24/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lasse Kristensen. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelSpeed: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "backgroundNotification:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil);

        // Set logo in nav bar

        navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))


        refresh();
    }
    func backgroundNotification(noftification:NSNotification){

        refresh();

        println("Refreshed after background")
    }

    func refresh() {


        // Global save values

        var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!



        // JSON Fetching

        let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=55.564120&lon=12.568605"

        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                if (error != nil) {
                    println(error)
                }
                else {


                    // Delete old entries in CoreData

                    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WindData")

                    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

                    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

                    for result in results! {

                        context.deleteObject(result as NSManagedObject)
                        context.save(nil)

                    }

                    // Start fetching JSON


                    let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary


                    var item = jsonResult["wind"] as NSDictionary

                    var degrees:Float = item["deg"] as Float
                    var speed:Float = item["speed"] as Float


                    // Start saving JSON

                    var newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("WindData", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

                    var speedValue:Float = speed as Float
                    var degreesValue:Float = degrees as Float

                    newItem.setValue(speedValue, forKey: "speed")
                    newItem.setValue(degreesValue, forKey: "degrees")

                    context.save(nil)



                }

                // Start fetching from CoreData

                var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WindData")

                request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

                var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

                if results!.count > 0 {

                    for result in results as [NSManagedObject] {


                        let degrees:Float = result.valueForKey("degrees")! as Float
                        let speed:Float = result.valueForKey("speed")! as Float


                        if speed > 6.0 {
                            self.labelSpeed.text = "Go kitesurf: \(speed) m/s \(degrees)"

                        }
                        else {
                            self.labelSpeed.text = "Stay in: \(speed) m/s \(degrees)"
                        }

                    }
                }
                else {
                    println("No data")
                }
            });
        })

        task.resume()


    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "app is view"?

Comment: I suppose I mean every time the viewController is displayed. Does that make more sense? Sorry, I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: Use the `viewWillAppear:animated:` or `viewDidAppear:animated:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and refresh your screen there.Put all code from `viewDidLoad` to helper function like `refreh` and call it when `viewDidLoad` or you come in foreground from background or whenever you want to refresh screen.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "backgoundNofification:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil);
   //put all code of your viewDidLoad to refresh 
   refresh();
}
func backgoundNofification(noftification:NSNotification){

    refresh();
}

func refresh() {
 //here is your all code to fetch data and all

}
```

Comment: In your code, you mention UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, so shall I change that to UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification instead?

Comment: No worrries. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction yet again!

Comment: It makes much more sense to use, viewWillAppear, since users shouldn't have to go to the background to refresh the content.

Comment: when application comes froreground from background `viewWillAppear` not get called.

Comment: Codester: Although your code works, it doesn't update the data. I included a println("Refreshed after entering foreground") to check if that part executes, and it does, but it doesn't seem to update the JSON. Could the issue be that the JSON takes a couple of seconds and therefore the code just use the old value?

Comment: Also, I have a NavigationController controlling my viewController, does that have an impact?

Comment: If i am getting right your point than Yes it take some time to fetch data from server and to load and if `json` is not changed than you will see old values.Print the json value and find if UI is updating after that.